# Upload AMPHTML to Google Ads error INVALID_BUNDLE: AMP

Tags: validation, amp-html, banner-ads

thanks in advance for helping.

I searched around for topics on uploading AMPHTML ad to Google. Can seem to get pass the INVALID_BUNDLE: AMP error in Google Validator.

How can we get our AMPHTML creative to Google ads?

I pasted this script from the AMP tutorial and changed my image location to and URL. Compressed the html file and image folder and uploaded to Google HTML5 Validator.

**AMP ad Tutorial link:**
https://go.amp.dev/documentation/examples/ads/style-layout/banner_ad/

**The script edited in Dreamweaver 21.3**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ⚡4ads lang="en">
    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>BlueCard</title>
      <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/amp4ads-v0.js"></script>
      <!-- ## Setup -->
      <!--
      As part of any other AMP document, we import the canonical boiler plate to make it a     valid AMP document.
      -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style amp4ads-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- ## Basic Usage -->
      <!--
      The anatonomy of banner ad is an image with a hyperlink to the advertiser's page. We     display the image for the creative using [amp-img](/documentation/components/amp-img).
      -->
      <a target="_blank"
         href="https://www.example.com">
        <amp-img src="images/bg.jpg"
                  width="300"
                  height="250"
                  layout="responsive"
                  alt="a4a image"></amp-img>
      </a>

      <!--
       We include a tracking pixel to record that the ad was rendered using [amp-pixel](/content/amp-dev/documentation/components/reference/amp-pixel-vundefined.md).

      Alternatively one could make use of [amp-analytics](/content/amp-  dev/documentation/components/reference/amp-analytics-v0.1.md) to enable much more   comprenhensive measure activity.
       -->
       <amp-pixel src="https://example.com/pixel?RANDOM"></amp-pixel>
    </body>
    </html>
```